# How to add a Favicon to an ExpressionEngine website?

Tags: file-uploads

I'm new to ExpressionEngine and was wondering if anybody could help me?

I added the code:  in the header in the home index through the Design -> Templates -> Edit -> Site -> index. I then uploaded the favicon.ico to the root folder using GoDaddy's FTP.

Is there anything I missing, because it's not working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There's not one way to do this with EE. It all depends on your code.

You should find the section (or sections) of your site templates that have the meta tags. Then add your favicon tag there too. To make sure you have the correct path to the favicon, open the favicon link in your browser.

Example:
`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`

Comment: Ok and thank you. Here the favicon has to be uploaded to the images folder, so it's web visible. I don't know why it's like that, but then I just re-linked it in the code and it works. So it said the root folder doesn't have permission for web visibility. However it works now. Thanks again! http://www.pioneerpolebuildings.com/images/favicon.ico

Answer (score 3):

If you have favicon.ico in your website root folder--i.e., so the favicon's URL is http://yoursite.com/favicon.ico, then you do **not** need to include a link to it in your HTML header. Browsers will automatically try /favicon.ico when they find no link in the header (and, some will try /favicon.ico even when do find a link in the header…).

However, if you do want to include links in your HTML header, and you can just use plain-old HTML, like:

```
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

Note that many browsers cache the favicon, and if they don't find it at first, they won't necessarily pick-up any code or image changes, right away. You can clear your browser cache, or try a different browser, to see the change.

I find that Chrome is actually pretty good at picking-up changed favicons.

Comment: Ok and yeah I just ended up using the link. Here the favicon has to be uploaded to the images folder, so it's web visible. I don't know why it's like that, but then I just re-linked it in the code and it works. So it said the root folder doesn't have permission for web visibility. So I just relinked it in the header and it works. http://www.pioneerpolebuildings.com/images/favicon.ico Then here is the root folder version and it just takes you to the home page, not the favicon image alone. http://www.pioneerpolebuildings.com/favicon.ico Thanks again!